# How can I save to PFObject as a Number

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Subject says it all: how can I save a number as a number with parse.com.

Using setObject and use an NSNumber?

Where could I have found this information? I didn't find it in the Docs of PFObject.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct in assuming you can just use an `NSNumber`. For example:

```
PFObject *gameScore = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"GameScore"]; 
[gameScore setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1337]
```

The iOS developer guide (which is distinct from the API docs) [runs you through this here](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-saving/iOS).